# task scheduler does not run when not logged in

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2008

I have created simple exe to perform a task using VB6. I have deployed the same on Windows Server 2008 as task scheduler. The issue is when the user is not logged in on server, task fails to execute.

I have kept option to "Run whether user is logged on or not", still no use.

Comment: I voted to close your question as it has nothing to do with programming. You may want to try asking this on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that it doesn't run. Task Scheduler keeps a history of what happened.

Most programs have some dependecy on the user profile and the user's configuration.

More likely your program is crashing. Look in TS's History tab. There's a general one and a task one.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with EXE as it runs perfectly when I am logged in on server. But If no one has session for that server, it fails and shows following error "Task fails as User not logged in".

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that. You can't see it so you can't know. Many programs won't run if not logged on. If you check a setting, try to use a mapped drive, write temporary files in certain ways your program won't work.

It's irrelevent that it works when you are logged on.

Try it with psexec from Sysinternals. This can run programs as system (unlike RunAs command). See what happens when you run it as system.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027.aspx

Whatever we need an error number. If your program doesn't have much error reporting then run it with windbg.

```
psexec -s windbg "c:\yourprogram.exe"
```

You can also start in a debugger.

windbg or ntsd (ntsd is a console program and maybe installed). Both are also from Debugging Tools For Windows.

Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Install the Windows SDK but just choose the debugging tools.

Create a folder called Symbols in C:\

Start Windbg. File menu - Symbol File Path and enter

srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

then

windbg -o -g -G c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k batfile.bat

You can press F12 to stop it and kb will show the call stack (g continues the program). If there's errors it will also stop and show them.

Type lm to list loaded modules, x *!* to list the symbols and bp symbolname to set a breakpoint

If programming in VB6 then this environmental variable link=/pdb:none stores the symbols in the dll rather than seperate files. Make sure you compile the program with No Optimisations and tick the box for Create Symbolic Debug Info. Both on the Compile tab in the Project's Properties.

Also CoClassSyms (microsoft.com/msj/0399/hood/hood0399.aspx) can make symbols from type libraries.

### .